# hibernate 4.3.0 2 level cache configuration

Tags: java, hibernate

In Hibernate version 3.X it's possible to configure 2 level cache in hibernate.cfg like this:

`<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>`

`<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</property>`

In version 4.3.0 there is no class `EhCacheProvider` in `org.hibernate.cache` package.

What is the workaround for this situation?

Thanks

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#performance-cache

Comment: Hi. The link states that in order to use `EHCache` I need a property `org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory`. Again, there is not such class there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**STEP 1** ***Add EHcache dependency***

Hibernate ships with the ehcache library

***1.1] Maven Dependency***

add maven dependency for Ehcache in your application as

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>[2.0.0]</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

***1.2] Download Jar file***

If you are not using maven dependency you can download the jars file from **[Download URL](http://ehcache.org/downloads/destination?name=ehcache-2.8.0-distribution.tar.gz&bucket=tcdistributions&file=ehcache-2.8.0-distribution.tar.gz)**
add this jar file into lib directory and your project `CLASSPATH`.

**STEP 2** ***Configuring EhCache***

To configure ehcache, you need to do two steps:

***2.1] configure Hibernate for second level caching***

```
<property key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
```

***2.2] specify the second level cache provider***

*Hibernate 3.3 and above*

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
```

*Hibernate 3.2 and below*

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider</property>
```

hope this will help you !

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exacetly what I was looking for. But now it throw  `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.EntityRegion`. And it's obvious that `EntityRegion` class is also missing from 'org.hibernate.cache' package. Should I add some other jar? Note: I'm not using maven dependency in ths project.

Comment: which hibernate version your using now ? its 4.3.0 right ?

Comment: have you added ehcache-core-2.4.4.jar file in your class path ?

Comment: Yes, hibernate 4.3.0. Downloaded ehcache-2.8.0-distribution.tar.gz, which contains only ehcache-2.8.0.jar (added to class path).

Comment: so you have to add ehcache-core-2.4.4.jar file to in your class path.

Comment: Sorry to say but this is about as useless as it gets. The question is about Hibernate 4 which is compiled against ehcache-core, which in fact is ancient, and new EhCache. It'd be much easier to say that new EhCache simply doesn't work with Hibernate. Period.

Answer (score 1):

Add below depenedency in your pom.

```xml
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
 <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
 <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
 <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
 <exclusions>
  <exclusion>
   <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
   <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
 </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Refer to this link: https://dzone.com/articles/hibernate-4-and-ehcache-higher